# What happens when I create nested DOM elements using jQuery as a string?

Tags: jquery, dom

What happens when I use the following, and is there any semantic difference?

### Method one:

```
var task = $('<li class="task"><header><h1></h1></header></li>')        
$('#backlog-tasks').append(task);
```

### Method two:

```
var task = $('<li>').attr('class','task');
task.append('<header>');
.....
```

*A secondary question: Is there an approach which you favour over the above?*

### Example

http://jsfiddle.net/Zwedh/2/

Comment: Do you want/need any more information than what is given in the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 If yes, what exactly do you want to know? You can also have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L106-L176).

Comment: @Felix, thanks I didn't see that page. So it appears that the first approach is parsed by the browser itself, and can have different effects dependent on the browser.

Comment: Method 1 is fine. However, don't go overboard with storing HTML source code strings inside JavaScript files. Method 2 is an abomination `:P`

Comment: But why are you adding that HTML string to the DOM anyway? Does your page ship without a H1 element, so that you need to insert one programmatically?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I'm creating a SCRUM board and each post-it note is created dynamically. I'm appending the task li (post-it) element to the product backlog ul element.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas i've added an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zwedh/2/

Comment: @Jack The 1. method is OK. Generating the new post-it via HTML string is the shortest and most readable way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the jQuery documentation, method 1 is parsed by the browser, while method 2 isn't. This is rather hard to find in the prose,

> ...jQuery **uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the passed HTML** and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, **the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed**.

but it definitely is there. (Emphasis mine.)

I tend to use method 2, for several reasons:

1. Doesn't rely on possibly-browser-specific stuff. (See above.)]
2. You don't have to worry about quoting quotes - jQuery does it for you.
3. What if you need an attribute's contents to be user-defined?

More on that last one. Say you need to set the `style` of some element according to user input (probably implausible, but I couldn't think of a better example).

### Method 1

```
$("<p style='" + input + "'>")
```

Now think about an `input` of `' onclick="$.ajax(/* some evil parameters */)" data-dummy='`. (Or I'm sure you can think of worse.) Not the most desirable thing ever.

### Method 2

```
$("<p>").attr("style", input)
```

Much better.